# Parameters are supposed to be distinct within a set of independent but not identically distributed random variables?

Tags: random-variable, independence

[image]

I'm confused here with one thing: If $(X_1,...,X_n)$ is not idenctically distributed, then doesn't this mean that the $\theta$'s are supposed to have subscripts $i$ in the pdf given above? I mean the $\theta$'s are not the same. Am I correct or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\theta's$ are the same, but the $c_i's$ are not.  The fact that each $X_i$ has its own $c_i$ is what makes the distributions not (necessarily) identical.